# Proof that $a(1) \equiv 0 \pmod{q} \Rightarrow (x-1)|a(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following result:

*Let $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})[X]$ with $q$ prime. Then* $$a(1)\equiv 0 \pmod{q} \;\Rightarrow\; (X-1)\,|\,a(X) \;\text{ in }\; (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})[X]$$

So far I have only managed to prove the converse. Any hint toward the right direction is therefore appreciated.

Comment: I have attempted to use polynomial long division to compute $a(X)$ divided by $X-1$. Is the point that the remainder should be $a_n+a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_0=a(1)$, and then we apply $a(1)\equiv 0 \pmod{q}$ to conclude that the remainder is zero, thus implying $(X-1)\,|\,a(X)$?

Comment: That would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a(X)= \sum a_k X^k$ then, since $a(1)=\sum a_k = 0 $ :

$a(X)= a(X)-a(1)=\sum a_k(X^k-1)=\sum a_k(X-1)(X^{k-1}+...+1)=\\(X-1)\times(\sum a_k(X^{k-1}+...+1) )$

Therfore $X-1 | a(X)$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.